# Turn Off Aptana Studio 3 (Mac) Autocomplete

Tags: aptana3

Exactly as the question states - does anyone know how to turn off Aptana 3 for Mac's autocomplete feature?  I'm referencing the javascript, css, html, php, etc. auto closing quotes, tags, etc. - it's extremely annoying, and I am unable to find anything clearly referenced online.  Thanks for any assistance.